# Getting a specific index in Regular Expression Ex: (test 1 test 2 test 3) I would like to match the second 'test'

Tags: php, regex

Getting a specific index in Regular Expression Ex: (test 1 test 2 test 3) I would like to match the second 'test', 
I'm using PHP preg_match

I tried to use preg_match_all but that is a slow function and I need high performance on this.

for example I have a HTML

I would like to match the third match

```
$str = "<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>";
preg_match('/<span>(\d+)<\/span>/',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Something like: '/(\d+)</span>[2]/'

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: So is it the third or the second?

Comment: I mistyped in the title, but it doesn't matter, the point is to get a especific index of a match.

Comment: What's wrong with `preg_match_all()` again?

Comment: preg_match_all brings all results and saves them, as I commented in the answer below, if I have 500 matches of the same word, and all I want is the match number 240, preg_match_all would save them all, when it could only ignore saving more time of processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match_all` is your best bet less xml parsing.
This will also work, but is very ugly:

```
/(?:<span.+?span>){2}<span>(\d+)<\/span>/


function regbuild($num) {
    return "/(?:<span.+?span>){". --$num ."}<span>(\d+)<\/span>/"
}
```

Comment: I know, works with preg_match_all, but I have for example, 500 matches, it would take much more time, when all I want is just the index 240, because preg_match_all would save all of them.

Comment: read my edits, if you don't want to use preg_match all, use my query function

Comment: the HTML code I get is very large, its not that simple like in the example: "<span>1</span><span>2</span>"; it has a lot of nested elements and javascript functions and css styles. thats why I wanted to know if theres a way to get a specific match.

Comment: No, your matches have to be uniform, my new edit is much better (don't know why it slipped my mind) `/(?:<span.+?span>){239}<span>(\d+)</span>/` will only select the 240th spans contents. If all of your elements are uniform, regex is your pal, otherwise you need to use an xml parser.